# Require inside Q promise

Tags: javascript, requirejs, q

I need to use require inside Q structure

```
Q.fcall(function () {
    console.log('1');
}).then(function () {
    console.log('2');
    require(['myfile'], function () {
        console.log('2.1');
    });
}).then(function () {
    console.log('3');
});
```

What I expect?

```
1 
2
2.1
3
```

What I got?

```
1
2
3
2.1
```

Is it possible? How I should to rewrite construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get `require` to work with a promise, otherwise you have two independent asynchronous systems. I didn't test, but something like this should work:

```
Q.fcall(function () {                                                           
    console.log('1');
}).then(function () {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    console.log('2');
    require(['myfile'], function (myfile) {
        console.log('2.1');
        deferred.resolve(myfile);
    }); 
    return deferred.promise;
}).then(function (myfile) {
    console.log('3');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of new to `promises` . Hence I am also not sure but can you try this:

```
Q.fcall(function () {
   console.log('1');
}).then(function () {
    console.log('2');
    return require(['myfile']);
}).then(function () {
   console.log('2.1');
}).then(function (){
   console.log('3');
});
```

Comment: Your promises are fine, but not your RequireJS. In RequireJS, `require` does not return a useful value, but passes it to a callback. Thus, you cannot use whatever is required in a next promise.